# Mounting a volume with docker in docker

Tags: docker

I'm running docker within a container using the command below:
`docker run --rm -ti --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker:1.12 sh`

Within that container's shell I see a directory with a bunch of files. Let's say `/project` with a file`build.gradle`. I'd like to start a new container and mount this directory using the command below

`docker run -ti --rm -v /project:/project openjdk:8-jdk bash -c "ls /project"`.

However it looks like the project directory is empty, the `ls /project` does not show any files..

Now trying to mount a file:

`docker run -ti --rm -v /project/build.gradle:/project/build.gradle openjdk:8-jdk bash -c "ls /project/"`

This time the folder shows the file.

Anyone who has an idea why the volume mount does not work as expected. Is this a permission issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nope. Inside the "docker" container, you only get a Docker client, not the whole thing. Once you mount the Docker socket inside your "docker" container, when you execute Docker commands, they go straight to the Docker "server" running on your actual Docker host. As such, that folder is expected to exist in your Docker Host.

Example how to mount a volume with docker in docker:

```
host$ pwd
/var/my-project

host$ docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $PWD:/app docker -it sh

/ # ls -l /app ### inside first docker
<LIST OF PROJECT FILES>

/ # docker run -v /var/my-project:/inception docker sh ### you need to pass HOST directory NOT currently running (/app) container directory

/ # ls -l /inception ### inside second docker
<LIST OF PROJECT FILES>
```

Comment: Confirm that, I've got the same issue and currently I can access only host files to last docker.

Comment: you made my day! I'm running gitlab and the runners inside AWS ECS. and inside the runner(dockerized) I had to run again docker. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing inside a container. To start an app with docker from docker and mount a volume, you can just mount the volume with the path from the host.

`docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./baseimage
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      # - ./<appsrc>:/app  # <= This doesn't work
      # Instead use the location of the volume on the host system
      # (where the docker socket is mounted from)
      - /c/Users/<user>/<container_folder>/<appsrc>:/app # <= this does work
```

now you can run `docker-compose up`

Of course this works only, when `<container_folder>` is mounted inside the docker container where you run this command.